how to avoid ( using pure javascript) setting cookies which are set by response headers set-cookie
I have a html page, to which I would like to insert a .html template which is stored in a separate file.  I have done it like this:
index.html:
<html>
<body>
  <script src="js/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/cookie_consent.js" type="application/javascript"></script>

  <div id="cookie-banner-container"></div>
</body>
</html>

cookie_consent.js

$(document).ready(function() {
  
    // Load the external header HTML into the page
    fetch('/html_templates/template.html')
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(html => {
            // set contents of template to specific div
            $('#cookie-banner-container').html(html);
        })
        .catch(error => console.error('Error loading template:', error)); 
    console.log("DOMContentLoaded banner");
});


template.html
<div id="mytemplate" > 
   any text
</div>

It all works fine, just when I fetch the template from the server of course I am doing a HTTP Reqest in ordet to get the file hosted on the server. Along with the response, my server is adding some cookies using the SET-COOKIE header:

I have tried to change the code to omit the headers by requesting the template like this:
   fetch('/html_templates/template.html', { credentials: 'omit' })

But the header is still there.
Is there any way I can "take" this html template and insert it into my index.html page to avoid the browser to set the cookies?
Additional information: I am using simple javascript with jquery (I am free to pick any other pure front end libs), I have no access to angular nor react. Also I am planning to load this template for around 100 files similiar to index.html, thats why I want to keep template in a separate file.

Instead of trying to fiddle your code, you could address the underlying issue: The usage of an F5 product which introduces this cookie in the first place? If you want to use their product, then you need to cookie, otherwise it cannot measure anything. If you don't want to use their product you can simply get rid of it and the cookie will disappear.

Dear @KIKOSoftware those are the requirements which I have for my current task and I am not in power position to change them. The f5 loadbalancer is a tool which I have no controll as I work for big corporation with separate teams and architecture strategies for all its products. There is more to this tool than just this one cookie so I would prefer to focus on my original question.
